# Taking specific data out of json file using node.js and filesystem

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I want to take title, body, id out from array but I don't know how. Using node.js and filesystem.

This is posts.json file:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
...
]
```

I tried with everything I found but nothing helped.

This is node.js file - top of the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('To see all posts add to url /api/posts.')
});
```

With this I get all array out but I need just first array element

Code continuation:

```
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  }else{
  res.json(JSON.parse(data))};
});
});
```

In json file array there is an element id that should go in id place in ({url}/api/posts/1) it's how needs to look like.

Code continuation:

```
app.get('/api/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
     console.error(err);
   } else {
     // here should go how to get element but nothing worked
   };
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`req.params.id` to access the URL parameter.
Iterate over the posts to find the correct post, otherwise respond with a not found status code.

```
const resArray = JSON.parse(data)
const post = resArray.find(post => post.id == req.params.id)
```

`===` won't work due to the parameter being a string.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Where to put them in code, Halldór R.?

Comment: @RičardsBainors Where you put 
```// here should go how to get element but nothing worked```

Comment: The biggest thanks! Halldór.R